# INSERT Corre en XAMPP pero no online

Tags: php, xampp, lampp

He configurado un servidor online ubuntu 18.04, php 5.6, mysql 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 en DigitalOcean

he desarrollado en xampp 5.6.37 .... en ambiente windondows .. pero no logro hacer que me funciones este insert

```
$query_tmp=mysqli_query($con,"select * from product_tmp where product_id='$product_id' and user_id='$user_id' and branch_id='$id_sucursal'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query_tmp);
if ($count==0){
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into product_tmp
    ( product_id, qty, unit_price, user_id, discount, branch_id, cventa)
    values ('$product_id','$qty','$unit_price', '$user_id','$descuento','$id_sucursal','$cventa')");
} else {
    $rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_tmp);
    $actual_qty=$rw['qty'];
    $new_qty=$actual_qty+$qty;
    $update=mysqli_query($con,"update product_tmp set qty='$new_qty' where product_id='$product_id' and user_id='$user_id' and branch_id='$id_sucursal'");
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te arroja. Saludos.

Comment: disculpa no me marca ningun error eso es lo raro ...

Comment: Haz un var_dump de la consulta

Comment: el va_dump arroja un bool(false) online y en xampp un bool(true)

Comment: Tienes un problema en la conectivdad a tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto **NO OLVIDES CONFIGURAR LOS PARÁMETROS DE LA CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "select * from product_tmp where product_id='$product_id' and user_id='$user_id' and branch_id='$id_sucursal'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
   $sql = "INSERT into product_tmp
( product_id, qty, unit_price, user_id, discount, branch_id, cventa)
values ('$product_id','$qty','$unit_price', '$user_id','$descuento','$id_sucursal','$cventa')";

} else {

  $actual_qty = 0;

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
     $actual_qty += $row['qty'];
  }

  $sql = "update product_tmp set qty='$actual_qty' where product_id='$product_id' and user_id='$user_id' and branch_id='$id_sucursal'";
}
?>
```

Comment: Revisando un poco esto estaba viendo que INstale Mysql en Ubuntu pero Xampp Corre con MariaDB ... probare cambiarlos.. a ver como me va